# Power Bi connection to Postgres docker instance on EC2

Tags: postgresql, docker, amazon-ec2, powerbi

As part of some reports on powerBi to be available, we want to establish a connection between powerBi to a postgres server that runs as a docker container in an EC2 instance.

The connect to postgreSql dialog on powerBi doesn't provide facility to establish a connection using an SSH tunnel to use my PEM file. Any workaround to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

Run Power BI Desktop and click Get Data.
Select the Other category in the Get Data dialog box, then select ODBC. Click Connect to confirm the choice.
In the From ODBC dialog box, expand the Data Source Name (DSN) drop-down list and select the previously configured DSN for PostgreSQL
If you would like to enter a SQL statement to narrow down the returned results, click the Advanced options arrow, which expands the dialog box, and type or paste your SQL statement.
Click OK. If your data source is password-protected, Power BI will prompt you for user credentials. Type your Username and Password in the respective fields and click.
Now you should see the data structures in your data source. You can preview the contents of the database objects by clicking on them.
To load the PostgreSQL data into Power BI for analysis, select the needed table and click Load.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).